# find number of occurence in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a string for example `'p2p3p4p9c5c6c7'` I want to make a select-statement in mysql that returns how much of those strings `('p6','p7','p8' or 'p9')` are containing in the initial string. 
The result of my example should be 1, because only 'p9' is containing in my string.
I don't find a good way to do that. Can someone help?

another example
`'k2p4p6p8p9c8'` the result should be here 3

Comment: So you will search all the strings at the same time or one string at a time ?

Answer (score 2):

You would seem to have a poor data format.  If you want to store lists of things, use a junction table.

However, the best answer that I can think of is a set of conditions that are added together:

```
select ((str like '%p6%') +
        (str like '%p7%') +
        (str like '%p8%') +
        (str like '%p9%')
       ) as NumInString
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

I should repeat that if the substrings are really codes of some type, then these should be stored in a separate junction table, with one row per code and original row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
(SELECT 'p2p3p4p9c5c6c7' AS a) AS string_table 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 'p6' AS b UNION ALL
SELECT 'p7' UNION ALL
SELECT 'p8' UNION ALL
SELECT 'p9') AS list_table
ON INSTR(string_table.a,list_table.b) > 0;
```